# How do I put XML code into IntelliSense comments?

Tags: c#, intellisense, xml-comments

I have the following code block.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// AMethod produces this XML:
    /// <A><B></B></A>
    /// </summary>
    public void AMethod()
    {
    }
```

When I do this IntelliSense does not print the XML, if I hover over AMethod. How do I get it to print the XML?

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the XML

```
    /// <summary>
    /// AMethod produces this XML:
    /// &lt;A&gt;&lt;B&gt;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/A&gt;
    /// </summary>
    public void AMethod()
    {
    }
```

This will then render the IntelliSense as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a CDATA section:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// <A><B></B></A>
    /// ]]>
    /// </summary>
```